# How to define a SPICE model based on an existed model in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, spice

I downloaded a BSIM3 model which contains a lot of parameters. Its definition is like this:

```
.MODEL CMOSN NMOS ...
```

Now I want to define a model based on this BSIM3 model which just adds W, L parameters.
I add this directive and modify the symbol model name.

```
.model MOSW CMOSN L=0.25u W=0.375u
```

[image]

When I run, I get the error message:

```
m2:Can't find definition of model "mosw"
```

The error log tells me:

```
Unknown model type "cmosn" -- ignored
```

It seems that this way not works. So how to define a SPICE model based an existed model?

Comment: You should be be able to simply right-click the `nmos4` or `pmos4` symbol and enter in unique W and L values for each specific instance.  If you need to change things other than W, L, AD, AS, PD, PS, or M on a per instance basis then you'll need to use the `ako` keyword.  More info here:  https://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_LTspice#AKO_Aliases_.28A_Kind_Of.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual for [NGSpice](https://ngspice.sourceforge.io/docs/ngspice-html-manual/manual.xhtml#cha_Behavioral_Modeling) gives the minimal model for a MOSFET as follows:

```
.MODEL MOSN NMOS level=number version=number.number.number
```

The word `NMOS` is a *device* keyword, indicating the name of a kind of device that Spice knows about.  (It is not the name of a "base" model.  Level defines the mathematical model.  See manual section 11.2)

You can give parameters in the instance or in another model.

So you take your

```
.MODEL CMOSN NMOS ...all the params...
```

and make

```
.model MOSW NMOS L=0.25u W=0.375u ...all the params...
```